# opencv-python compiled fail in apple m1 chip

Tags: numpy, opencv, apple-m1, python

I installed Tensorflow-macos and try to install opencv-python
but always fail in this message

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sean/Documents/sysvenv/tf24v/bin/python3 /Users/sean/Documents/sysvenv/tf24v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/gy/jzs3xnwd1z3203d75y_31nxc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-en64krht/overlay --no-warn-script-location -v --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.

it lookalike the bumpy version problem.
But In Tensorflow-macos it it 1.8.5 and python is 3.8
Does anynoe have the same problem?
thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Downloaded Tensorflow-macos and Python 3.8 from Xcode command line tools like so https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/tag/v0.1alpha1. Tried running pip install opencv-python in virtualenv and it's failing.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at these suggestions:

- [opencv issues with M1 MAC - OpenCV imshow doesnot work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278632/opencv-issues-with-m1-mac-opencv-imshow-doesnot-work)
- [conda install opencv](https://github.com/neurolabusc/AppleSiliconForNeuroimaging)

I was successful in installing [Python 3.9.1 for Apple Silicon](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download) and then running `conda install opencv`. However, the slow time to compute a few functions for the first time might suggest some components are still being translated via Rosetta. Regardless, while I did not test performance the functions I needed seemed to work.

Comment: I tried to install it several times with `pip` with no success and installing it with conda did actually work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

after searching the web I have successfully installed OpenCV on my Mac M1.

1. Probably you don't have *brew* installed, so here's how you should install it:

   - `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
   - `brew install wget`
   - `brew install miniforge`
   - `brew install cmake`, you will need cmake for building OpenCV code
2. Then just follow this blog: https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/#Install-conda

   - OR, here is the YouTube video which explains the second step: https://youtu.be/x_kAkabk-5o

P.S. If  `mdfind cv2.cpython` returning an empty string then try to delete the `build` folder and compile opencv again. Otherwise, you have done everything correctly.